# Using CoordinatorLayout in fragments with ActionBar in Activity

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have problem using Android Design Support Library. I would like to use CoordinatorLayout inside fragment for FAB and ActionBar animations while scroll, but I having ActionBar in activity layout and my CardGridStaggeredView and FAB in fragment.

activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout   <!--Here I display fragments-->
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        app1:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                style="@style/FragmentTheme"
                tools:context="androidhive.info.materialdesign.activity.HomeFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.extra.staggeredgrid.view.CardGridStaggeredView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                card:list_card_layout_resourceID="@layout/carddemo_extras_base_staggered_card"
                style="@style/main_layout_foreground"
                android:id="@+id/cgvImages"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to use CoordinatorLayout in Activity and Fragment, but it didn't work. Is any way to use CoordinatorLayout with ActionBar in Activity and other views in fragment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have Activity with DrawerLayout and Fragments with CoordinatorLayout working just fine (pay attention where fitsSystemWindows attributes are set)

here is activity layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/color_primary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/menu_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/bm_white"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:divider="@null" />
            <!-- Картинки - fb, vk, twitter  -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and fragment's xml with coordinator, action button etc:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--NOT SET HERE: android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- NOT SET HERE:  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic_top_main" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="32dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- In code now… -->
            <!--<include layout="@layout/fragment_start_nonfc"/>-->
            <!--<include layout="@layout/fragment_start"/>-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClickPurchase_Remote"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_purchase"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Now it's working, but my CardGridStaggeredView isn't visible in NestedScrollView. If I delete NestedScrollView Cards are visible, but then animations not working.

Comment: Yep... not all combinations work with current controls.
Try to put your controls inside android.support.v7.widget.CardView

So that hierarchy is 

<NestedScrollView>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <RelativeLayout or your other layout inside
   </CardView>
  </NestedScrollView>

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. I'm trying to get the backdrop painted behind the status bar, but it's still painted below using your code. Is there anything else missing? I have the `fitsSystemWindows` flags set exactly as you have. Is there any code that needs to go in the fragments?

Comment: In fragment I have:
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  setupToolBar((AppCompatActivity) getActivity());
 }

 protected Toolbar setupToolBar(AppCompatActivity a) {
  toolBar = (Toolbar)getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  if(toolBar == null) return null;

  a.setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
  a.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
  return toolBar;
 }

Comment: and i got this code in my MainActivity.java mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close); and i dont know how to use custom toolbars for each fragment when i need to put the toolbar there in my MainActivity.java

Comment: so your solution is put the ActionBar and CardGridStaggeredView inside one layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution, the activity layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_bottom_layout">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.funvideo.videoinspector.photopick.ui.widget.TitleView
                android:id="@+id/title_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_title_bar_height"
                android:background="@color/simple_title_bg_default_color"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_title_bar_height"
        android:background="@color/simple_title_bg_default_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:text="预览"
            android:textColor="@color/social_color_4"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/album_list_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_title_bar_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.funvideo.videoinspector.photopick.ui.widget.AlbumListView
            android:id="@+id/album_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="@color/album_list_bg"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/album_outside"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the `main_container` is the place where I append my fragment in my activity:

```
val fragment = YImageMainFragment.newInstance(album)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, YImageMainFragment.TAG)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

and the layout of fragment is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/lot_empty_resources"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tips_item_bg"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lot_go_filechoose"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txv_file_choose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="还是无法解决？可尝试使用文件浏览方式选取照片或视频～"
                android:textColor="@color/color_t1"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_go_file_choose"
                android:layout_width="162dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/yellow_button_selector"
                style="@style/LegacyButton"
                android:textColor="@color/tip_pop_txt_color"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="去选取"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

not extra code needed, it run as my expected, this could be the versions, below are mine:

```
appcompatVersion=1.3.1
recyclerviewVersion=1.2.1
com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0
```