# Android Tab Layout is not showing the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tabactivity

Hi I have the following issue , when pressing a tab icon the view is not shown, i can see the class is being loaded. I can see the that in the console log. I believe the issue is related the the xml as i have moved the relative layout main_content below the view pager and when the icon is pressed in the tab layout, the tab fragment content is shown but the main content views don't attach then which is a problem.

**My Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </RelativeLayout>


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_pane"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <!-- Profile box -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_mail_black_24dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phong"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PTIT HCM"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Navigation Listview -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nav_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_box"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice">

        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `CoordinatorLayout`, Let's use that `NavigationDrawer` too.

**Here what you should exactly do (StandardWay):**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <!-- Your Contents -->

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
    <!-- navigationdrawer menu -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Not sure if this is a good implementation :**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_pane"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
```

**especially, with this one:**

```
<!-- Navigation Listview -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/nav_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_box"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

Here you learn more about using this `CoordinatorLayout` with contents and mastering it:

http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator/

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, the tabs work, but i need a relative layout to push fragments into (main_content) container, where should i add that too ?

Comment: I added to the nestedScrollview and im getting the same problem as my code, the tabs work where they can be changed with the icon, but when i push another fragment to the view it loads the class, but not the view

Comment: That is an another issue, check this link for solving that problem too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31719032/4409113 you can use it outside of the `NestedScrollview` you can check this example too : https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout

Comment: i think i will need to go back to the drawing board on this one, as im going round in circles, thanks for the link, i will read that and use that as a base. Thank you.

Comment: Yw, you'll need it in future again :) so, let's learn it from base.goodluck